# C++ "No Matching Function for call to" Error

Tags: c++, linked-list, build-error, polynomials

I'm expanding off of code given to us. I have to finish creating a program that can add two polynomials together. When I try and compile though, I get these build messages.

```
Line 17: error: no matching function for call to 'Term::Term()'

Line 10: note: candidate: Term::Term(float,int)

Line 10: note: candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided

Line 6: note: candidate: Term::Term(const Term&)

line 6: note: candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided.
```

I'm not quite sure what is wrong, this is our first C++ programming assignment. The TA provided most of this code, I added everything in the final while statement. I also added `float coef;` and `int exp; to the Node structure.

The coding I used in the while statement was how the Professor explained how to run through the polynomials and check. Does anyone have any idea on how to solve my error?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Term {
    float coef;
    int exp;
public:
    Term(float c, int e) { coef = c; exp = e; }
    void set_values(float c, int e) { coef = c; exp = e; }
    float get_coef() { return coef; }
    int get_exp() { return exp; }
};

template <class T>
struct Node {
    float coef;
    int exp;
    T data;
    Node * next;
};

template <class T>
class LinkedList {
public:

    LinkedList() : head(NULL), size(0) {};
    ~LinkedList();
    bool addNode(T data);
    bool deleteNode(T data);
    Node<T> * searchNode(T data);
    void printList();
    void reverseList();
    Node<T>*  get_head() { return head; };
private:
    Node<T> * head;
    int size;

};

template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList() {
    Node<T> * tmp = NULL;
    while (head) {
        tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        //cout << "deleting data " << tmp->data << std::endl;
        delete(tmp);
    }
};

template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::addNode(T data) {
    try {
        Node<T> * tmp = new Node<T>();
        tmp->data = data;
        tmp->next = head;
        head = tmp;
        ++size;
        return true;
    }
    catch (std::exception & ex) {
        return false;
    }
}

template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::deleteNode(T data) {
    Node<T> *current = head, *prev = NULL;

    while (current) {
        if (current->data == data)
            break;

        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    if (current) {
        if (prev)
            prev->next = current->next;
        else
            head = current->next;

        delete(current);
        --size;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

template <class T>
Node<T> * LinkedList<T>::searchNode(T data) {
    Node<T> * tmp = head;
    while (tmp) {
        if (tmp->data == data) {
            return tmp;
        }
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}



template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::printList() {
    Node<T> * tmp = head;
    bool printNewLine = (tmp) ? true : false;
    while (tmp) {
        std::cout << "(" << tmp->data.get_coef() << "," << tmp->data.get_exp() << ")";
        tmp = tmp->next;
        if (tmp)
            std:cout << ", ";

    }

    if (printNewLine) {
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::reverseList() {
    Node<T> *curr = head, *prev = head, *save = NULL;

    while (curr) {
        save = curr->next;
        curr->next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = save;
    }

    head->next = NULL;
    head = prev;
}

int main() {
    LinkedList<Term> p, q, s;
    Term pt1(2.0, 4), pt2(3.0, 3), pt3(-7, 0);
    p.addNode(pt3);
    p.addNode(pt2);
    p.addNode(pt1);

    Term qt1(-5.0, 5), qt2(3.0, 3), qt3(-7.0, 2), qt4(5.0, 1), qt5(-13.0, 0);
    q.addNode(qt5);
    q.addNode(qt4);
    q.addNode(qt3);
    q.addNode(qt2);
    q.addNode(qt1);

    p.printList();
    q.printList();

    Node<Term> * p_ptr, *q_ptr, *s_ptr;
    p_ptr = p.get_head();
    q_ptr = q.get_head();
    s_ptr = s.get_head();

    cout << "Coef: " << p_ptr->data.get_coef() << " Exp: " << p_ptr->data.get_exp() << endl;
    p_ptr = p_ptr->next;
    cout << "Coef: " << p_ptr->data.get_coef() << " Exp: " << p_ptr->data.get_exp() << endl;
    while (1) {
        if (!p_ptr && !q_ptr)
            break;
        else if (p_ptr->exp==q_ptr->exp){
            if (p_ptr->coef + q_ptr->coef != 0) {
                s_ptr->coef = p_ptr->coef+q_ptr->coef;
                s_ptr->exp = p_ptr->exp;
                p_ptr=p_ptr->next;
                q_ptr=q_ptr->next;
            }
            else {
                p_ptr=p_ptr->next;
                q_ptr=q_ptr->next;
            }
        }
        else if (p_ptr->exp > q_ptr->exp){
            s_ptr->coef = p_ptr->coef;
            s_ptr->exp = p_ptr->exp;
            p_ptr=p_ptr->next;
        }
        else (q_ptr->exp > p_ptr->exp); {
            s_ptr->coef = q_ptr->coef;
            s_ptr->exp = q_ptr->exp;
            q_ptr=q_ptr->next;
        }

        //else if exp of p_ptr > exp of q_ptr
            //copy the current term of p to r
            //p_ptr = p_ptr->next

        //else if exp of q_ptr > exp of p_ptr
            //copy the current term of q to r
            //q_ptr = q_ptr->next

        //else if exp of p_ptr == exp of q_ptr
            //add coef of p to coef of q
            //copy the resultant term in r
            //p_ptr = p_ptr->next
            //q_ptr = q_ptr->next
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Term` class does not have a default constructor.

The `Node` template class only has a default constructor. The `Node` class cannot be used with `Term` as a template parameter; perhaps excepting the special case of aggregate initialization.

So, for example:

```
Node<T> * tmp = new Node<T>();
```

This constructs a new instance of the `Node` template class, using its default constructor.

If the template class's parameter is your `Term` this will, of course, attempt to construct `Term` with a default constructor. Since `Term` does not have a default constructor, you get your compilation error:

```
Line 17: error: no matching function for call to 'Term::Term()'
```

And this is exactly what this error message says. An attempt was made to construct an instance of `Term` using its default constructor, but the class does not have one.

You must either define a default constructor for `Term`, or have `Node`'s constructor take `T` as a parameter, to copy-construct its `data` member.

Comment: Ahh okay, I see. I added a line in the public section of the Term class that reads simply Term() {}. Is this good enough for what I'm doing? Or is there a more proper way to do this?

Comment: @CabooseMSG, Now you have a `Term` with uninitialized data. Is that appropriate? Depends on its purpose (i.e., that's ultimately for you to decide).